# Change of Variable to a Moving Frame

Tags: fluid-dynamics, calculus

I'm trying to derive the equations shown in this paper ([link](https://link.aps.org/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.77.775)), which I'll copy here.

The motion of a cell in response to a chemical gradient is described by overdamped dynamics as

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = r \frac{d}{dx}f(x+vt) $$

where $f$ describes the concentration of a chemical signal moving to the left with a velocity $v$. Next, a coordinate $z \equiv x + vt$ is defined in the moving frame of the signal. Now

$$ z = x + vt $$
which means
$$ \frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt} + v = r \frac{df(z)}{dx} + v $$

Then the author writes
$$ \frac{dz}{r \cdot df(z)/dz + v} = dt $$

How does the derivative with respect to $x$ become derivative with respect to $z$ with no other term? Doesn't $dz$ equal to $dx + vdt$?